# Anomalous behaviour adding more than one cell to a TableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have this TableView

[image]

When the view appears it works fine, when I add a row it works fine too, when I add a second, third, ecc... row it starts having this issue:

[image] (instead of having only the segment going down, it displays both)

Segmet is build with a dot image fixed and two middle segments: one up and one  down and, depending from the row, I display one the top segment, or only the bottom or both:

```
    cell.centralDotIV.image = UIImage(named: "Dot")
    if array.count > 1 {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell.lowerLineIV.image = UIImage(named: "Line")
        } else if indexPath.row == array.count - 1 {
            cell.upperLineIV.image = UIImage(named: "Line")
        } else {
            cell.upperLineIV.image = UIImage(named: "Line")
            cell.lowerLineIV.image = UIImage(named: "Line")
        }
    }
```

Here's the code which runs every time the button to add the cell get tapped:

```
@IBAction func addDateTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    array.append(NSDate())

    var i = 0
    var indexArray = [NSIndexPath]()
    for _ in array {
        let index = NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0)
        indexArray.append(index)
        i++
    }

    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    if array.count != 1 { tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(indexArray, withRowAnimation: .Fade) }
}
```

I tried even reloading the table every time button get tapped but is the same. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not updating your cells properly when they are dequeued. You have to unset the image you don't need.

```
cell.centralDotIV.image = UIImage(named: "Dot")
if array.count > 1 {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.lowerLineIV.image = UIImage(named: "Line")
        cell.upperLineIV.image = nil
    } else if indexPath.row == array.count - 1 {
        cell.lowerLineIV.image = nil
        cell.upperLineIV.image = UIImage(named: "Line")
    } else {
        cell.upperLineIV.image = UIImage(named: "Line")
        cell.lowerLineIV.image = UIImage(named: "Line")
    }
}
```

And you should not play with the `image` property so often. Instead, set the `image` to `UIImage(named: "Line")` once and for all and in your controller :

```
cell.centralDotIV.image = UIImage(named: "Dot")
if array.count > 1 {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.lowerLineIV.hidden = false
        cell.upperLineIV.hidden = true
    } else if indexPath.row == array.count - 1 {
        cell.lowerLineIV.hidden = true
        cell.upperLineIV.hidden = false
    } else {
        cell.upperLineIV.hidden = false
        cell.lowerLineIV.hidden = false
    }
}
```

Which you can factorize :

```
    cell.lowerLineIV.image = UIImage(named: "Linea")
    cell.upperLineIV.image = UIImage(named: "Linea")

    if DataManager.sharedInstance.actualAction.iteration_action!.count > 1 {
        cell.lowerLineIV.hidden = indexPath.row == array.count - 1
        cell.upperLineIV.hidden = indexPath.row == 0
    } else {
        cell.lowerLineIV.hidden = true
        cell.upperLineIV.hidden = true
    }
```

Comment: With your "factorisation" you won everything!!

Answer (score 0):

@Matte.Car as if array.count !=1 you are reloading all rows of table view, for every insertion of new record. So, is it possible for you to use tableView.reloadData() method as it does same.
Secondly, can you show your code for CellForRowAtIndexPath().

Answer (score 0):

Table view cells are typically reused for performance reasons. So you need to configure them completely or implement the approriate "prepareForReuse" pattern.